# Long story short, we need to automatically active the Show On Lock Screen permission on Android devices using React Native?

Tags: android, react-native

We are building an app using React Native and we couldn't give the Show On Lock screen permission for the app automatically. Some applications are doing that such as Whatsapp, Telegram, or Alert applications. Especially on miui devices it's a bit of a challenge. Is there anyone who can help with that?

[An example image describing the permission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5oJnR.jpg)

Comment: Please don't compare your app to system and pre-installed ones (maybe even "most popular" from the store). In most cases its phone manufacturer that put them on an "allow list" and you won't get around that.

Comment: But for example, forget about to system and pre-installed ones. How can Telegram achieve that, mate? Or WhatsApp. I know you wrote that "most popular" ones but they managed it somehow.

Comment: My point is phone manufacturers can arbitrarily decide what apps they deem safe to grant those permissions by default (don't look for a pattern but "most popular" ones will be there), I'm saying there isn't much you can do as a developer.